# Why does explicitly declaring one of the special member functions disable generation of others

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

Is this a technical requirement that it cannot be done by the compiler in any way or pure security-wise suggestion that is enforced?

Comment: What do you mean by "special member functions"? Can you please show an example (with code) what you mean?

Comment: It is a set of rules of the language, mainly to make it hard to implicitly generate badly behaving code. But it is not as simple as you state. Explicitly declaring *some* special member function *can* disable generation of *some* of the other ones.

Comment: Search for The Rule Of Three/Five

Comment: I know the conditions and I know the rule of three/five. I am asking what the reason behind it is.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I am not asking the conditions. I am asking the reason of those conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the reason is not technical.

The auto-generated special member functions are designed to act somewhat like POD/C-style `struct` similar operations, but extended.  This makes C++ types act slightly more uniformly.

But not all types should behave that way.  C++ stops auto generating some according to rules set down in the standard for purely language/code design reasons -- it was decided removing them was better than leaving them in to be called by surprise or through inexperience.  Probably had the language been designed today, the rule or 3/5 would be explicit in how member function auto generation is implicitly disabled.

C++11 adds `=default` as a way, among other things, to bring them back.

Move special member functions both had to deal with C++03 backward compatibility, and not breaking existing code.   There is no technical barrier here either, just language design and backward compatability issues.